# Validate all inputs with regex Attribute in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I need to validate that all the inputs on my asp.net page doesn't allow next characters:

>
<
?
//
\
&

How can I add a rule to all the inputs of my app at the same time without adding [RegularExpression...] to every field?

I have more than 500 fields on my entire app. It is an app full of forms.

Comment: If you want to change the standard behaviour of a control and it should be reusable, too, TagHelpers are your friend. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/authoring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I had to solve an issue like this, I would probably create a ModelBinder that could validate the field.  This code isn't tested, but should be somewhere close.

```
public class DangerousCharacterModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
    public override  bool OnPropertyValidating(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor, object value)
    {
        if(value is string)
        {
            bool valid = true;
            // Do your regex test here to change the valid flag

            if(!valid)
            {
                bindingContext.ModelState.AddModelError(propertyDescripter.Name, "Your error message here");
            }
        }

        return base.OnPropertyValidating(controllerContext, bindingContext, propertyDescriptor, value);
    }
}
```

Then in your global.axax.cs Application_Start method, you would register it with:

```
ModelBinders.Binders.DefaultBinder = new DangerousCharacterModelBinder();
```